# Store Global Variables for different environments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

in my Rails application I also try to test my calls to Redis. For example in my User Model I have:

```
def self.add_to_visibles user #To show in the menu
    $redis.lpush("user_visibles", user.to_json(only: [:vorname, :nachname, :id, :created_at]))
end
```

Now when i run this test, also test data is inserted into the redis store `"user_visibles"`. That means when I am on development I also get to see this data.

Thats why I would like to change my method to:

```
def self.add_to_visibles user #To show in the menu
    $redis.lpush($user_visibles, user.to_json(only: [:vorname, :nachname, :id, :created_at]))
end
```

And store in `$user_visibles`:

for test: `$user_visibles = "user_visibles_test"`

and for production `$user_visibles = "user_visibles"`

Where do I best store this variable? And how so that it is different for the environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

config/user_variables.rb

```
Rails.configuration.user_variable =  YAML::load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/user_variables.yml")[Rails.env]
```

and create the config/user_variables.yml like this

```
production: 'user_visibles'
test: 'user_visibles_test'
```

Remember to restart your server

You have to get the value with Rails.configuration.user_variable where you need it